# Data mining to gather a website's details and put in CSV or SQL

Tags: data-mining

I don't know if it's called data mining or something else.

Let's say I have a world business listing site, that list all the shops. And I saw this website ABC that also list shops, but only in Ausralia. They are in page by page, with no ID.

How do I start to write a program, that will crawl their pages, and put in the selective information of a page in the format of CSV, which I can then import it to my website?

At least, where can I learn this? Thank you.

Comment: I think what it's called is theft.

Comment: It's called "scraping". Data mining is normally used in the context of databases, where you are searching for some sort of patterns in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is known as "Web Scraping", here's a good starting point for information, including the legal issues

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

One common framework for writing crawlers like this is Scrapy- http://scrapy.org/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this process called Web Scraping. If you are familiar with java, most useful tools here is  HTMLUnit and WEbDriver. You should use headless browser to go though you pages and extract important information using selector(mostly xpath, regexp in html format)